# Generating html with Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let historyHtml = [];


function createHistory() {
    const htmlArray = historyHtml.map(item => {
        return `
        <div class="history-delete-content">
            <button class="icon-delete">
                <i class="ri-delete-bin-2-line"></i>
            </button>

            <div class="history-content ${item.numberInputValue === '-' ? 'expence-history' : ''}">
                <p>${item.textInputValue}</p>
                <span class="number">${item.numberInputValue}</span>
            </div>
        </div>`;

    });


    const html = htmlArray.join('');

    document.querySelector('.history-delete-container').innerHTML = html;
    
}



function addHistory() {
    const textInput = document.querySelector('.text-input');
    const textInputValue = textInput.value;

    const numberInput = document.querySelector('.number-input');
    const numberInputValue = numberInput.value;

    const historyItem = {textInputValue,numberInputValue};

    historyHtml.push(historyItem);
    console.log(historyHtml);


    textInput.value = '';
    numberInput.value = '';
    createHistory();
}

document.querySelector('.add-button').addEventListener('click', addHistory);
```

If the number class is minus (-) value, I want to make my history-content content red, which is green in the javascript code, by assigning a class, but I can't get a result. What is the reason?

Comment: why would `"-2" === "-"` ?

Comment: Why not simply `numberInput.valueAsNumber < 0`?